# IIS Reverse Proxy to a Jetty Server

Tags: iis, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have an application that I have to do some integration with that is using the Jetty web server. The company that makes the application gave me instructions on how I could use IIS to act as a reverse proxy and forward all traffic to the jetty server using Application Request Routing. The instructions were:

```
1) Create a Server Farm in IIS
2) Create a URL Rewrite rule to direct all traffic to the server farm.
```

Looking at the URL Rewrite rule, it is using a wildcard match (*) to route all traffic to the server farm that was set up. This is problematic for me because now every website that was on this server is trying to redirect traffic to the jetty server.

Is there a way where I can only have traffic for a single IIS site redirect traffic to the server farm?

Here are the specifics:

Jetty Web Server is hosting its site at:
    `http://mymachinename:7777/foo`

I have an IIS site that is running at: (I don't want traffic from here to go to Jetty)
    `http://mymachinename:50295`

If I get a request at this URL, I want to redirect it to jetty:
    `http://mymachinename:8888/*`

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just put jetty directly on the internet? Get an IP or use it on another port than 80 as you are already doing.

Comment: 1) This app is not available on the internet. 2) This is beyond my control. I do what is asked of me.

Comment: The main reason is that nobody here knows Jetty. Everyone knows IIS so it's much easier to configure things using IIS instead of Jetty.